# Solving recurrence relation. Recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation 
$$f(n) = 2f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)$$
with initial conditions $f(0) = a, f(1) = b$. (here a and b are fixed, arbitrary integers).

Can anyone show me how to solve this? a and b are fixed, arbitrary integers. Does it mean I can put any value for a and b?

Comment: `Does it mean I can put any value for a and b?` It means that you need to find an expression for $f(n)$ in terms of $n$ and $a,b\,$.

Comment: This is a [homogeneous recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) which you can solve as the Wikipedia link suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The roots of $x^2-2x-1$ are $1\pm\sqrt{2}$. Hence, there exists $(\alpha,\beta)$ such that:
$$f(n)=\alpha(1+\sqrt{2})^n+\beta(1-\sqrt{2})^n.$$
Using initial conditions, one has:
$$a=\alpha+\beta,b=\alpha+\beta+(\alpha-\beta)\sqrt{2}.$$
Solving for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, one has:
$$f(n)=\frac{b-a+a\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}(1+\sqrt{2})^n+\frac{a-b+a\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}(1-\sqrt{2})^n.$$

If you are wondering how I derived the closed form for $f(n)$, I have recently explained it [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291307/mathematical-olympiad-treasures-problem-1-58-solution-missing-steps/2291311#2291311).

Answer (score 0):

General technique is to use generating functions. Define:

$\begin{equation*}
  F(z)
    = \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n) z^n
\end{equation*}$

Shift to get rid of substractions in indices, multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n + 2) z^n
    &= 2 \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n + 1) z^n
        + \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n) z^n \\
  \frac{F(z) - f(0) - f(1) z}{z^2}
    &= 2 \frac{F(z) - f(0)}{z} + F(z) \\
  \frac{F(z) - a - b z}{z^2}
    &= 2 \frac{F(z) - a}{z} + F(z)
\end{align*}$

Solve for $F(z)$, write as partial fractions:

$\begin{equation*}
  F(z)
    = -{{\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\,b+\left(-2^{{{3}\over{2}}}-3\right)\,a
 }\over{2^{{{3}\over{2}}}\,\left(z+\sqrt{2}+1\right)}}-{{\left(\sqrt{
 2}-1\right)\,b+\left(3-2^{{{3}\over{2}}}\right)\,a}\over{2^{{{3
 }\over{2}}}\,\left(z-\sqrt{2}+1\right)}}
\end{equation*}$

If you have a term $(1 - \alpha z)^{-1}$ in the partial fraction decomposition, if gives rise to a term $\alpha^n$ in the solution. Other typical terms are:

$\begin{align*}
  (1 - \alpha z)^{-m}
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} 
         (-1)^n \binom{-m}{n} (\alpha z)^n \\
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0}
         \binom{m + n - 1}{m - 1} (\alpha z)^n
\end{align*}$

giving rise to to a polynomial in $n$ multiplying $\alpha^n$.